# How to remove 'giambja01' from DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a Data Science Related project. I need to remove a certain name from my DataFrame. here is what I attempted:

```
delete_row_1 = batsal[batsal["playerID"]=='giambja01'].index
remaining_players = batsal.drop(delete_row_1)
```

To test whether this worked I wrote this and got False:

```
'giambja01' in remaining_players['playerID']
 False
```

It seems to have worked. and yet when i run the following code i get this:

```
remaining_players['playerID']
10836    giambja01
13287    heltoto01
2446     berkmla01
11336    gonzalu01
8271      drewjd01
25101    pujolal01
17276    lawtoma02
82       abreubo01
5395     catalfr01
10852    giambje01
22174    nevinph01
20635    mientdo01
6275     coninje01
11545    gracema01
20173    mclemma01
23005    ordonma01
24596    pierrju01
22418    nixontr01
5903     clarkto02
30281    sweenmi01
20688    millake01
18086    loducpa01
11810    grievbe01
3145     boonebr01
29869    stewash01
33183    whitero02
32039    vidrojo01
Name: playerID, dtype: object
```

I am attaching a sample DataFrame:

```
batsal = pd.DataFrame({'playerID':['giambja01' , 'damonjo01' , 'saenzol01'],'Sex':['M','M','M']})
```

Please let me know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is drop works with columns and not rows. Instead you have to designate the index of the item you would like to remove and the columns data should be removed from. You should try:

df.drop(index='giambja01', columns='1').

Answer (score 0):

Try this, specifying the index:

```
remaining_players = batsal.drop(index=delete_row_1)
```

Find the documentation on the function [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).